# Blank line when inserting code template in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been working with customizing the formatter in Eclipse to suit my style and I finally feel like it seems to do it exactly as I want it to except when inserting templates.

Whenever I use any Eclipse template (for example "Add unimplemented methods") it inserts a blank line before the code, even though the "Blank Lines" settings is set to 0 for "Before method declarations".

Anyone who knows how to disable this blank line or do I have to remove it manually every time?

Comment: If you Clean Up your code, it should remove that line.

Comment: @Jeffrey I tried that but the line is still there, probably because I have set Eclipse to preserve one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue with Eclipse too, and it's been a pet peeve of mine for some time.  I believe it's a bug, because it has nothing to do with the formatting settings at all - turning off all 'new line' features and setting all 'blank line' parameters to 0 still doesn't fix the issue.  You might want to report it as a bug.